# mysql query logic involving the same column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to come up with a way to extract some info from a mysql (5.6) table. I have 4 columns of interest: cname, path, file, and hash. I'm looking for files that have the same hash AND exist with BOTH cnames h1215 and h1216. For example, suppose the entire table was the following:

```
cname path      file     hash
h1215 c:\temp   abc.txt  123
h1215 c:\temp   abd.txt  213
h1216 c:\temp   abc.txt  123
h1216 c:\temp   bce.txt  678
h1216 c:\temp\a bce.txt  678
```

I'm looking for the rows with hash 123 in this case (#1 and 3). Obviously there will be more than one match, and a particular hash may, and does, appear more than once for either cname. Further, I won't know the hash list in advance without a lot of manual work. Here there is only one, but in my real data set, there are likely to be about 3900. Ideally, I would just get back a list of matches, so 1 row in this example, either #1 or #3. I don't want row 4 or 5, as that exists only on h1216.

So far, the best I've come up with is the following statement:

```
SELECT * , count( hash ) AS hashcount FROM `files` WHERE (`CName` = "h1215" OR
cname = 'h1216') AND Path LIKE 'c:\\\\temp\\\\%' GROUP BY hash HAVING hashcount >1
```

This is close, but it doesn't guarantee me that the hash appears on BOTH h1215 and h1216. It could appear on just h1216 more than once for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your example what you want your count to show, but this query should get you close to what you want

```
SELECT *, count(hash) AS hash_count from files WHERE 
cname = 'h1215' 
AND path LIKE 'c:\\\\temp\\\\%'
AND hash IN 
(SELECT hash FROM files WHERE cname = 'h1216') 
GROUP BY hash
```

This will get you all the hashes which match h1215 AND h1216

Comment: Not sure how it works, but it does. I would have thought the "where cname = 'h1215'" would have eliminated any results containing h1216, but it doesn't.

Comment: P.S. The count was just to get hashes that appeared more than once. Obviously, counts of 1 don't appear on both h1215 and h1216.